# 502 Bad gateway when running default laravel app while other php files work

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I´m trying to install laravel (tried 5 and 4) but am continously getting a 502 bad gateway error.

Searching on the net resulted in some answers about wrong permissions for the unix-socket. But my php setup for an other domain using the exact same parameters functions as you would expect.

This is the setup/configuration after a clean install of the framework via

```
/data/$ laravel new myapp
```

nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /data/myapp/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.net;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

ls -ahl /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

```
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Nov  4 10:05 /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

in www.conf (configuration of the php part)

```
 listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
 listen.owner = www-data
 listen.group = www-data
```

As stated this configuration works just fine with the exact same settings. The only thing changed to the server-directive is the `server_name` and the `root`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Is there anything in the laravel log?

Comment: Where can I find this log? The /myapp/storage/logs folder is completely empty.

Comment: As far from a .gitignore, its empty.

Comment: What's in nginx error.log ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is something going on with Zend's OPCache. If you disable it in `php.ini`, like so

```
opcache.enable=0
```

The app suddenly works.

Why? I don't know, and that bothers me. But for now it works. If anyone knows the reason behind this: i'll accept your answer instead of mine.

Comment: Just wanted to add: I'm setting up Laravel 5 with separate Docker containers for Nginx and PHP-FPM. I've exhausted all the other answers on SO and the internet about this 502 Bad Gateway problem; none of them have worked for me. This one did it, and I'm just as disturbed as you are that I don't know why. I hope to find an answer in the future. Anyway thanks for the tip.

Comment: Same happened to me. I had to install Zend Opcache 7.0.5 in an old php 5.3.2 server, and I got the 502 error. Only disabling opcache makes the error go away.

Comment: Does Laravel sucks? Well, if framework can't be normally installed without pain in your ass, then yes, it heavily sucks.

Comment: Not sure if it's Laravel problem - I hade similar issue with Wordpress, Prestashop and some Silex based websites. Some (not all) php sockets crashed silently (no message in logs) after enabling opcache.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there could be some errors in your nginx config.
So I created a brand new app on my VPS, using your nginx config. Just like you, I got a 502 Bad Gateway error. Then I copied a config file that works fine, and I got "Error in exception handler." error after running it. It shows that nginx works fine with my Laravel app, but only has some permission issues.
Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;
    root /root/to/yourapp/public;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Then I run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /root/to/yourapp/app/storage/
```

Then the app works perfectly.
Hope this could help you.

Comment: this didn´t work. The thing different to this configuration file is the fast_cgi_pass parameter denoting an IP:port instead of a socket. My php is setup to function via a unix socket; as this works fine for other non laravel projects....